# Acessar classes, id's, div's de uma página com minha extensão

Tags: javascript, dom

Olá, estou escrevendo uma extensão com o seguinte objetivo: acessar os elementos alvos de uma pagina (tipo document.querySelector('.jobs')) e a partir daí escrever o restante das instruções. Porém, pelo que eu li, scripts de conteúdo acessam o DOM em um ambiente isolado (por isso quando solicito "DOCUMENT" retorno como se o DOM da página estivesse vazio) e queria um help sobre como posso resolver isso. Detalhe: ja pesquisei sobre o assunto em tudo qualquer site de dev, inclusive o http://developer.mozilla.org. Antes de desistir do projeto vim tentar uma última luz aqui. Valeu gente.

edit:
**background.js**

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: 'https://www.sine.com.br/vagas-empregos-em-contagem-mg'}, function(){
    console.log('criada');  
  });
});
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: "execute.js"
      });
```

**execute.js**

```js
setInterval(() => {
    var vagasList = document.querySelector('.jobs').childNodes;
    n = [];

    vagasList.forEach(element => { 
      if(element.nodeName != '#text') {
        var enfia = n.push(element.children[0].children[1].href);
        var ind = n.indexOf(element);
        if (ind > 2) {
          n.splice(ind);
        }
      }
    });

    n.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
      open(element);
      vagas = setInterval(function(){
        document.querySelector('.pnl-candidatar').children[0].click();
        console.log('ok');
      }, 1000);  
      
    });
  }, 5000 );
```

Comment: Se vc postar o código fica mais fácil de obter ajuda.

Comment: ta ai os codigos

Answer (score 0):

vamos analisar a assinatura do `create` e do `executeScript`

[`create − chrome.tabs.create(object createProperties, function callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create)

o segundo argumento do `create`, é uma função de `callback` que recebe a [`Tab tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab)

[`executeScript − chrome.tabs.executeScript(integer tabId, object details, function callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

Agora do `executeScript` recebe como parâmetro do `tabId`, então é netural que se execute o `executeScript` no callback do `create`.

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  active: true, 
  url: 'https://www.sine.com.br/vagas-empregos-em-contagem-mg'
}, function(tab) {
  console.log("Tab criada", tab)
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: "execute.js"
  }, function (results) {
    console.log("Script executado", results)
  });
});
```

Sem informar o `id` da `tab`, o script seria executado em todas as `abas`, isto traria um risco de segurança.

Comment: correção aplicada ! Agora como faço pra acessar o document.querySelector('.jobs').childNodes??